# dm365 mpeg4 encoder P-Frames

Tags: c, ffmpeg, embedded, mpeg-4

I am implementing the operation of encoding video with TI DM365 mpeg4 encoder and containerizing it with ffmpeg mp4 container using a dummy FMP4 codec to produce headers and footers. While the container is proven to be working correctly using similar Intel based mpeg4 encoder, the dm365 gives a mosaic result if P frames are used at all. Using only I frames works, but I would like to minimize amount of data stored.

The example of the result can be viewed [here](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Discussions-Components-Files/100/0336.test.mp4). Settings are 1-Iframe, 9-Pframes

TI developers didn't answer my question regarding this in 2 days, so I am trying to get help here.

Comment: Pro-tip : TI dev rarely answer questions

Answer (score 0):

This may help, a TI data sheet on the various settings/parameters and their effect. Apologies if it is telling you stuff you already know...
[TI Data Sheet spraba9.pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraba9/spraba9.pdf)